# Change in the state of a struct stored in a QVector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, struct, qvector

I can't understand what's wrong with this part of code:

```
struct aliance {

    ...

    void setFirstTeam(const team& _team) {
        firstTeam = _team;
    }

    void setSecondTeam(const team& _team) {
        secondTeam = _team;
    }

}     

QVector< aliance > _aliances;  

...     

_aliances.at(i).setFirstTeam(firstAlianceTeam);
_aliances.at(i).setSecondTeam(secondAlianceTeam);
```

I get errors:

```
passing 'const aliance' as 'this' argument of 'void aliance::setFirstTeam(const team&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
passing 'const aliance' as 'this' argument of 'void aliance::setSecondTeam(const team&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I've already retried at least all variants of these two functions with `const` and without one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QVector<T>::at()` returns a `const T&`, which means you can't call non-const member functions on the result (such as your `setFirstTeam()` function). Why Qt doesn't provide a non-const overload is <s>beyond me</s> related to Qt's copy-on-write semantics for its containers (thanks to @peppe for pointing this out). It does provide both overloads for `operator[]`, so you should just do this instead:

```
_aliances[i].setFirstTeam(firstAlianceTeam);
```

Comment: Because `at` is meant to avoid detaching, and it makes it obvious that you're not touching the container's contents. `operator[]` has instead const overloads. In other words: `vector.at(i).constMethod()` would cost a full copy of the vector if the vector weren't declared const.

Comment: @peppe Oh, right. I forgot about Qt's copy-on-write semantics for containers.